# Time diff in days

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following snippet:

```
import datetime as dt
end_date = dt.datetime(2020,04,12,10,30,0,0)
current_date = dt.datetime(2020,04,10,0,0,0,0)
diff = end_date - current_date
days = diff.days + (1 if diff.seconds > 0 and diff.days > 0 else 0)
```

I need 0 when day is the same and 1 or more when day > 1.

Examples:

> time difference is 2 days and 4H: should give 3
>
> time difference is 0 days and 4H: should give 0

How can can improve the following?

```
days = diff.days + (1 if diff.seconds > 0 and diff.days > 0 else 0)
```

Comment: Does this work as intended?

Comment: In the code provided, both dates are the same. This is not going to do much good.

Comment: @Peilonrayz yes it is.

Comment: Why `current_date`? Why not `start_date`, just like you got `end_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. You can split calculating the days to two lines if you think it's more readable that way.

```
# Calculate full day difference
# Assuming negative difference should be 0
days = diff.days if diff.days > 0 else 0
# Add one if not exactly the same clock
days += 1 if diff.seconds > 0 else 0
# Or a little bit shorter
days += 1 if diff.seconds else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is required to have difference based on days I solved by removing time on dates and calculating difference by days count:

```
end_date = end_date.date()
current_date = dt.date.today()
diff = (end_date - current_date).days
days_left = diff if diff > 0 else 0
```